# Magento and configuable products for a printing service site

Tags: magento

I am building a webshop in magento for an online printing service. The functionality I’m looking to implement is something in the lines of this example.

http://www.digitalroom.com/secure/brochures.html

The price is affected by the configurations you choose, and also there is a discount for ordering larger quantities.

I have made my products as configurable products and set up the pricing for each individual simple product. But magento seems to disregard the pricing of the simple products and solely base the price on the configurable product.

Is this the right way to set this up? Or is there another best practice to set this kind of product up in magento?

If it is the right way, how do I get Magento to act on the pricing structure under the simple products instead of the one under the configuable product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products) extension.

Comment: Yes, I found it shortly after posting here. It simply saved my day. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.